Traefik Unable to Route Traffic to Docker Compose Setup
I'm having trouble configuring Traefik to route traffic to my wallet-service container within a Docker Compose setup. Although I can access the service directly via curl http://localhost:3000 on the host machine, Traefik fails to connect, attempting to reach an internal Docker IP (192.168.64.4:3000) instead of the mapped host port.
What I've Tried So Far

Configured Traefik with Proper Labels:

Specified internal ports in Traefik labels.
Ensured services are connected to the same Docker networks.


Verified Service Accessibility:

Direct curl requests to localhost:3000 return the correct response.
Confirmed that wallet-service listens on all interfaces (0.0.0.0).


Checked Traefik Logs:

Enabled debug and access logs in Traefik.
Observed Traefik attempting to connect to 192.168.64.4:3000.



Despite these configurations, Traefik cannot route traffic to my wallet-service.
Docker Compose Configuration
version: '3.8'

services:
  wallet-service:
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.entrypoints=websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.tls.certresolver=myresolver'
      - 'traefik.http.services.wallet-service.loadbalancer.server.port=3000'
    networks:
      - internal-network
      - traefik-public

  caller-service:
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.caller-service.rule=Host(`caller.${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.caller-service.entrypoints=websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.caller-service.tls.certresolver=myresolver'
    networks:
      - internal-network
      - traefik-public

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - internal-network

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.rule=Host(`rabbitmq.${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.entrypoints=websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.tls.certresolver=myresolver'
    networks:
      - internal-network
      - traefik-public

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    name: wallet-postgres-data

networks:
  internal-network:
    driver: bridge
  traefik-public:
    external: true


Traefik Configuration
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=sesto@post.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG" # Increase log verbosity
      - "--accesslog=true" # Enable access logs
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/var/log/traefik/access.log"
      - "--log.filepath=/var/log/traefik/traefik.log"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "./logs:/var/log/traefik" # Mount a volume for logs
    networks:
      - traefik-public

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
    name: traefik-public


Relevant Logs
When visiting the public domain, Traefik attempts to connect to 192.168.64.4:3000, which does not correspond to the host's port mapping. However, accessing http://localhost:3000 directly on the host returns the expected response:
curl http://localhost:3000
Service is running!


I believe you need to traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.tls=true for services reachable via websecure, like this:
services:
  traefik:
    image: docker.io/traefik:v2.9
    command:
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--accesslog=true"
    ports:
      - "7080:80"
      - "7443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - traefik-public

  wallet-service:
    image: docker.io/traefik/whoami:latest
    environment:
      WHOAMI_PORT_NUMBER: 3000
      WHOAMI_NAME: wallet-service
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.rule=Host(`wallet.example.com`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.entrypoints=websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.wallet-service.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.services.wallet-service.loadbalancer.server.port=3000'
    networks:
      - traefik-public

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true

Given the above configuration, If I run the following:
curl --resolve wallet.example.com:7443:127.0.0.1 -k https://wallet.example.com:7443

It successfully connects to the wallet service.
Note that I've enabled the dashboard here, which can be accessed at http://<container_ip>:8080. Having access to the dashboard is critical when trying to debug your Traefik configuration. You can leave it enabled and simply not expose the api port.

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.
